# Can I de-rockify rocky terrain in SMAC

Tags: alpha-centauri

Is there any way to terraform rocky terrain in SMAC, so that it is no longer rocky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMAC Wiki [says](http://alphacentauri2.info/wiki/Level_Terrain) that

> Terraforming Units can use **Level Terrain** to decreases the rockiness level of a square. It can be used to turn rocky squares into rolling squares and rolling squares into flat squares.

Is this what you need? Can it be that you meant the opposite command, "Rockify"? It is, indeed, absent.

See also: [**Terraforming**](http://alphacentauri2.info/wiki/Category:Terraforming)

Comment: That's it, thanks. Underscore is the hotkey/

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, thanks for upvoting and accepting my answers. I've seen four consequent upvotes and I believe they are from you. While I appreciate that, I should mention that serial voting is discouraged at Stack Exchange network and so your votes may become reverted soon. The threshold seems three per day per my posts. If you really want to upvote my old questions, please do so in several different days. :)

Comment: I honestly cant remember. I think that I just looked at the SMAC tag. There are only 24 questions, so I read most (all?) of them and probably upvoted quite a few answers and comments, certainly not only yours. Let's hope that you don't lose any upvotes